# Having Trouble Clicking in Date Field with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape a table from the 1/30/2022 slate. However, I get the 'unable to locate element' error when I attempt to click in the date field and change the date from 2/6 to 1/30. I've tried finding by class name as well. Is there another way to do this, or is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
from ast import Return
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import time

path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get('https://rotogrinders.com/resultsdb/nfl')

time.sleep(5)
driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(10)

search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="navbar-demo1-mobile"]/div[1]/div/span/div')
search.click()


previous = driver.find_element_by_class_name('react-datepicker__navigation react-datepicker__navigation--previous')
previous.click()

time.sleep(5)

date = driver.find_element_by_class_name('react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--030
```

react-datepicker__day--weekend')
date.click()

Comment: Your date class name are actually class names use css selector. Also it's not even closed off properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to find it because it is inside an iframe. You have to switch to iframe window first, and then try to access the element.

Also, I see that the date picker has enabled to key in the dates, so you could use `send_keys` to type in the date. It makes your code a little easier on you perhaps. But you may write to click on the date picker ui. It's your choice per se.
Having said that here is the code:

```
driver.get("https://rotogrinders.com/resultsdb/nfl")
time.sleep(10)
frame = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
date_picker = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='react-datepicker__input-container']//input")))
date_picker.send_keys("01/16/2022")
time.sleep(10)
```

Try to change the `time.sleep` to explicit wait if possible (`webdriverwait`)

Comment: had to maximize the window after driver.get, but this worked. tyvm

Comment: yes, I missed to mention about maximize window. It's just that I wrote that line just above driver.get and I missed to mention that when the window is not maximized, the component goes into the hamburger

Answer (score 1):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,60)
driver.get('https://rotogrinders.com/resultsdb/nfl')
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe")))
date = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.react-datepicker__input-container input')))
date.send_keys("01/16/2022")
```

First wait for the iframe and then proceed to click the search element and then send keys.

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: this worked as well. tysm!!

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to avoid Selenium here. It's just a matter of pulling out some id's to feed into the direct url.

```
import requests
import datetime
import pandas as pd

dateStr = input('Enter date (YYYY-MM-DD): ')
dateStr_alpha = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr, '%Y-%M-%d').strftime('%Y%M%d')

url = f'https://service.fantasylabs.com/contest-sources/?sport_id=1&date={dateStr}'
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()
groupId = jsonData['contest-sources'][0]['draft_groups'][0]['id']


url = f'https://service.fantasylabs.com/live-contests/?sport=NFL&contest_group_id={groupId}'
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()

tables = {}
for each in jsonData['live_contests']:
    contestId = each['contest_id']
    if each['contest_name'] not in tables.keys():
        tables[each['contest_name']] = {}
        

    url = f'https://dh5nxc6yx3kwy.cloudfront.net/contests/nfl/{dateStr_alpha}/{contestId}/data/'
    jsonData = requests.get(url).json()
    
    
    contestUsers = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['users']).T.reset_index(drop=True)
    tables[each['contest_name']]['users'] = contestUsers
    
    fieldExposures = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['players']).T
    
    
    for k, v in jsonData['exposures'].items():
        exposureDf = pd.DataFrame(v['exposureCounts']).T
        exposureDf.columns = [x + f'_top_{k}%' for x in exposureDf.columns]
        fieldExposures = pd.merge(fieldExposures, exposureDf, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True )
        
    fieldExposures = fieldExposures.fillna(0).reset_index(drop=True)
    tables[each['contest_name']]['exposures'] = fieldExposures
    
    print('****** ' + each['contest_name'] + ' ******')
    print(contestUsers,fieldExposures )
```

**Output:**

Now just call the table by its contest name:

```
print(tables['NFL $100K Conference Special [$20K to 1st]'])
```

[image]

Comment: how did you find these URLs? this works amazingly when i go to pull every Sunday from the year, but it only captures the first contest from each date. if i want all, can i do [0::] instead of just the [0] in groupid and contest id?

Comment: you find it by looking in the Dev Tools to see where the requests for the data are made. Ya to get other contests, just need to iterate through them. I adjusted the solution to do that.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: is there a way to do that to the Leaderboard table?

Comment: @TroyMcClure8998 I’ll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: @chitown88 no rush. thank you for looking at it

Comment: @TroyMcClure8998, which leaderboard table are you referring to? btw, I like the screenname - “If A Cow Ever Got The Chance, He'd Eat You And Everyone You Care About.”

Comment: thank you I wish it was my legal name too. I am referring to this https://ibb.co/2W2G4mC. Please let me know if you need any more info. God bless you I tried ever think using selenium but you found the best way so far.

Comment: @chitown88 https://rotogrinders.com/resultsdb/nfl link btw make sure to change the date to 02/13/2022

Comment: @TroyMcClure8998. Yup, got it. Post up a quesiton and I'll post the solution there